# Is there a catalog of Excel RibbonX editor XML code for the existing menus?

Tags: excel, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I'm working in the Office RibbonX Editor and I'm trying to reuse the show|hide gridlines from the view tab on my custom tab.  I can't find how to duplicate that in my xml.  Any idea's on either how to do that, or where I can find the code used in the view ribbon so I can duplicate that.

Comment: Are speaking about the backstage UI? A screenshot can be helpful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is amazing.  Found this site with all the code to replicate and Mso ribbon code from any windows tab and use it in your own custom tab.

Hope this helps others building their own custom ribbons in excel!

Here is what I needed to recreate the show|hide gridlines in the Office Ribbonx Editor:

```
<box id="SH2" boxStyle="horizontal"> 
<checkBox idMso="GridlinesExcel" />
<box/>
```

Cheers

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win016.htm

Scroll to the bottom of his page and you'll see links to the following:

Download example files?
But how do you know the RibbonX to duplicate the groups in the Ribbon, in the downloads below you can find the RibbonX to hide the built-in groups and to duplicate them so you have full control to change them the way you want.

Download this file from the Microsoft site: Office 2010: [Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

Download this file from the Microsoft site: Office 2013: [Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

Download this file from the Microsoft site: [Office 2016: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745)

See also github : https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers

Excel 365 idMso's (9-July-2020), in the example files I duplicate every group in the Ribbon.

Note: Will add the Draw tab soon

[Download Excel 365 example files](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/idMso-Excel%20365.zip)